# Trying to move or lower the opacity of the "close" button in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

Im trying to move the "close" button on a fancybox for youtube.  Whenever i try to add code like :

```
'onComplete': function(){
   $("#fancybox-close").css({"opacity":"0.5"});
}
```

The link just goes straight to Youtube, instead of playing inside a modal box.

any suggestions?

[image]

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqRPrGeBVL0&autoplay=1&autohide=1" >Youtube</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
$("a.fancybox-media").click(function() {
     $.fancybox({
          'padding'             : 0,
          'autoScale'   : false,
          'transitionIn'        : 'none',
          'transitionOut'       : 'none',
          'title'               : this.title,
          'width'               : 680,
          'height'              : 495,
          'autoPlay'            :'true',
          'href'                : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"),
                                      'v/'),
          'type'                : 'swf',    // <--add a comma here
          'swf'                 : {'allowfullscreen':'true'} // <-- flashvars here
       });
       return false;
  });
 });
```

NOTE -

Comment: any feedback to the answers provided? or not convinced you got the right answer yet?

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the other question, add to your script

```
'onComplete': function(){
 $("#fancybox-close").css({"opacity":"0.5"});
}
```

just make sure that you separate the options with a **comma** like:

```
$("a.fancybox-media").click(function() {
 $.fancybox({
  'padding'             : 0,
  'autoScale'   : false,
  'transitionIn'        : 'none',
  'transitionOut'       : 'none',
  'title'               : this.title,
  'width'               : 680,
  'height'              : 495,
  'autoPlay'            :'true',
  'href'                : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
  'type'                : 'swf', 
  // the swf option IS NOT the last option anymore so it needs a trialing comma !!!
  'swf'                 : {'allowfullscreen':'true'}, // <-- ADDED a comma here
  'onComplete': function(){
    $("#fancybox-close").css({"opacity":"0.5"});
  }
 });
 return false;
});
```

**DEMO**: See it [working here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/dimCloseButton_07jun12.html)

**Side notes**: if you add another option, like `overlayColor` to change the background color, always make sure that every option is separated by a `comma` but the last.

**UPDATE**: If you want to change the opacity **AND** move the close button, do it within the same `onComplete` option like

```
'onComplete': function(){
    $("#fancybox-close").css({"opacity": 0.4,"right": -30});
  }
```

[I updated the DEMO too](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/dimCloseButton_07jun12.html)

**UPDATE #2** (just for fun): You could apply interesting effects like restoring the opacity of the close button on mouse hover (everything within the `onComplete` option) like

```
  'onComplete': function(){
    $("#fancybox-close").css({"opacity": 0.4,"right": -30})
      .hover(function(){
        $(this).css({"opacity": 1});
      },function(){
        $(this).css({"opacity": 0.4});
      });
   }
```

(also updated in the DEMO)

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the CSS?

```
#fancybox-close {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

Comment: can you change the overlay color (the color of the screen behind the video) to white, with css too?

Comment: Yes the black too would be in the CSS depending on which style you're using. Have you found the CSS file it is using? http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions

Comment: yea i added the opacity code to
#fancybox-buttons a.btnClose {
 border-left: 1px solid #111;
 width: 38px;
 background-position: -57px 0px; 
}

and it didn't work